# Mac OS announcing notifications

Tags: mac, notifications, speech

There is an option in Mac OS to announce alerts, when they are displayed or to have it announce the time in regular intervals.

My question is: Is there an option to announce notifications, or even better a way to select which app's notifications should be announced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to speaking notifications, this does not appear to be possible in OS X 10.9, Mavericks. Please take the opportunity ask for this feature via [Apple's feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).

You can however have the time announced at regular intervals. The setting is in the **Date & Time** panel of **System Preferences**:

[image: Date and Time]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

The Notification system doesn't support Text-To-Speech and it's not supported by Accessibility.